# Monitor on D-SUB is missing resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, screen, display-resolution, dvi

I have two identical monitors 24" iiyama. One connected on DVI one on D-SUB (VGA). The one on digital sees 1920 x 1080 but the analog sees only 1360 x 768 which is too low. On Windows both monitors have the correct resolution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Always prefer digital. Use a HDMI to HDMI connection if available in the graphics card.

Comment: That wont be available when I get a third monitor. Only two digital ports on my card.